# Navigate table <tr> with keyboard Up/Down Arrows

Tags: javascript, html

I searched a lot to find a solution for this but I didn't found clear explanation. I actually have table (listing data from mySQL database with PHP) & I want it to be navigable with keyboard arrows: when the user press the up or down arrow, it focuses on the row above/over and that the background color changes. I want to learn how to do this in JavaScript please not the jQuery solution

Here is the table:

```html
<table id="pokemons-list">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>NO</th>
                      <th>Nom</th>
                      <th></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <?php
                   include 'database.php';
                   $pdo = Database::connect();
                   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM pokemons ORDER BY id ASC';
                   foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                            echo '<tr tabindex="-1">';
                       
                            echo '<td style="text-align:center">'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>'. '<img style="vertical-align:middle;margin: 0px 0px 0px -20px;" src="icons/'. $row['id'].'.png"></td>';
                       
                            echo '</tr>';
                   }
                   Database::disconnect();
                  ?>
                  </tbody>
            </table>
```

Also the table has a search bar which filters rows with this script :

```js
function searchPokemon() {
    
            var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
            input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("pokemons-list");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    
                for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
            
                    if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                
                if (found) {
            
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                    found = false;
                } else {
            
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does selecting a cell do or look like?

Comment: Have you tried yourself? If so, what did you do? Share!

Comment: @Feathercrown I want that when the user press the up or down arrow, it focuses on the row above/over and that the background color changes

Comment: Alright @Nas I've made an answer. If it's what you're looking for feel free to click the checkmark to accept it and give an upvote; if it's not just tell me and I'll see if I can change it when I get home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this as your JS:

```
var rows = document.getElementById("pokemons-list").children[1].children;
var selectedRow = 0;
document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
    //Prevent page scrolling on keypress
    e.preventDefault();
    //Clear out old row's color
    rows[selectedRow].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    //Calculate new row
    if(e.keyCode == 38){
        selectedRow--;
    } else if(e.keyCode == 40){
        selectedRow++;
    }
    if(selectedRow >= rows.length){
        selectedRow = 0;
    } else if(selectedRow < 0){
        selectedRow = rows.length-1;
    }
    //Set new row's color
    rows[selectedRow].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFAA";
};
```

I've made a quick example of this working on a more basic table:

```js
var rows = document.getElementById("pokemons-list").children[1].children;
    var selectedRow = 0;
    document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
        //Prevent page scrolling on keypress
        e.preventDefault();
        //Clear out old row's color
        rows[selectedRow].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        //Calculate new row
        if(e.keyCode == 38){
            selectedRow--;
        } else if(e.keyCode == 40){
            selectedRow++;
        }
        if(selectedRow >= rows.length){
            selectedRow = 0;
        } else if(selectedRow < 0){
            selectedRow = rows.length-1;
        }
        //Set new row's color
        rows[selectedRow].style.backgroundColor = "#8888FF";
    };
    //Set the first row to selected color
    rows[0].style.backgroundColor = "#8888FF";
```

```css
th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="pokemons-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>NO</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!--In your case this is auto-generated-->
        <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>Charmander</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td><td>Squirtle</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td><td>Bulbasaur</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td><td>Pikachu</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td><td>Arceus</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but I don't know why this is not working on my table @Feathercrown

Comment: Is there a way to get the HTML of your table once it's generated? I might be able to help you there. Also, make sure to put the Javascript after the table.

Comment: I get an error : "Cannot read property 'children' of null at list.php:10" and when my table is generated it's a serie of <tr><td>1</td><td>Bulbizarre</td><td><img src="icons/1.png"></td></tr><tr>

Comment: Alright! It's working I've put the Javascript after the table as you said, just a last question, I'm using this table with a search bar and when the table is filtered it's not working well, a solution for this please ? @Feathercown

Comment: I'd need to see the HTML of the filtered table to find a solution.

Comment: I added the filter script at the end of question, I tried something like : for (var tr[i] of table) { rows--;} and moved the variables declaration out of their respective functions to put them at the beginning of script but it didn't work. Thank you for helping me understand!